# How to set max length for "Bunifu .NET UI Framework" text box?

Tags: bunifu

I have developed a windows form application using Bunifu .NET UI Framework.

But I have a problem, I want to set max length of the text box.

Therefore please give me some advice, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can likewise use the method below:

```
/// <summary>
/// Sets the maximum length of text in Bunifu MetroTextBox.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="metroTextbox">The Bunifu MetroTextbox control.</param>
/// <param name="maximumLength">The maximum length of text to edit.</param>
private void SetMaximumLength(Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuMetroTextbox metroTextbox, int maximumLength)
{
    foreach (Control ctl in metroTextbox.Controls)
    {
        if (ctl.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
        {
            var txt = (TextBox)ctl;
            txt.MaxLength = maximumLength;

            // Set other properties & events here...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this method apply all text box or not? I want to apply max length only one textbox. not another one.

Comment: No, just one. Once you specify the BunifuMetroTextBox to set the `MaxLength` value when calling it, it will only change the specified instance. For example, say you have dragged a BunifuMetroTextBox named `metroTextbox1` in your Form, all you'll need to do when using the above function is: `SetMaximumLength(metroTextbox1, 20)`, with `20` being the maximum length of text editable in the specified MetroTextBox. Hope this helps...

Comment: great brother. Thanks, It's working. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code - add the code on form load or your constructor like **BunifuMetro(yourtextbox);** after InitializeComponent(). You can try and switch between the controls by replacing **Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuMetroTextbox** with another textbox; Cheers

```
  private void BunifuMetro(Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuMetroTextbox metroTextbox)

        {
            foreach (var ctl in metroTextbox.Controls)
            {

                if (ctl.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))

                {
                    var txt = (TextBox)ctl;
                    txt.MaxLength = 5;
                    // set other properties & events here
                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: BunifuMetroTextbox hasn't "MaxLength" feature in the properties window. But normally we can use like "textBox1.MaxLength = 40;" this code or change properties. However, only this code doesn't work in BunifuMetroTextbox. So what I'm doing now?

Comment: Have you tried the code workaround above? The property **MaxLength** is not available in the properties window that is why you need to solve your problem using the code provided.

Comment: Then how can write above code for only one BunifuMetroTextbox? please guide me and thanks for your advice.

Comment: Call the function **BunifuMetro(variable name of your text box);** in your form load.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way, Assign the MaxLength property on TextChange event of the textbox (Working 100%)

```
    int maxLength=5;
    private void textbox1_TextChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textbox1_TextChange.MaxLength = maxLength + txtActivationKey.PlaceholderText.Length;
    }
```